# scope.$on can't update directive scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I have some problems with my directives. I can't update my scope's inside directive using scope.$on. There is my code example.

```js
function linkdir1(scope){
        element.bind('click',function(){
            scope.$emit('someEvent',scope.data,scope.data2); //emit to parent directive
        });
}

function parentDir($scope){
         $scope.$on('someEvent',function(e,data,data2){
           $scope.$broadcast('broadcastEvent',data+data2);
        });
  }

function linkdir2(scope){

          scope.$on('broadcastEvent',function(e,data){ // i can see this data but can't update scope then.
            data == 0 ? scope.show = false : scope.show = true;
        });  
  }
```

```html
<div parent-dir>
  <div dir-one></div>
  <div dir-two></div>
</div>
```

I tryed using scope.$watch but this doesn't work.
Thanks for help.

Comment: try scope.$apply(); at the end of the event handler.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tuyukavufo/edit?html,js,output  - try to change the $scope.data variables in OneCtrl to see it's working

Comment: Can you please paste your directive code ?

Comment: Thanks @sdfacre . closed :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. I guess I will just put it as an answer, so other people find easily find it. And it'd great if you could accept it, if it solves your problem. :)

add

```
scope.$apply();
```

at the end of the event handler.

Comment: I have one questions.  I used scope.$apply two times, and the next use show we alert about $digest, i fixed it used $evalAsync and it's working, but it's the only one solution for it?

Comment: why do you need two scope.$apply? can you show me the code?

Comment: I need it for update other directive. I just used $apply in two directives and i got this $digest problem.

Comment: here is the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/mvYBQHPq99XF6vCUCt0o?p=preview which doesn't have error you described. feel free to change and save it, so I can have a look.